# ¿Cómo hacer en MySQL INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE y dos claves unicas?

Tags: mysql, insert

Teniendo en cuenta que (iduser y dni_nif) juntos tienen que ser únicos, intento hacer esto:

```
INSERT INTO contactos
            (iduser, tipo, codigo, nombre, dni_nif )
VALUES
            ('1','cliente','1','Juan','500000'),
            ('1','cliente','2','Maria','500001'),
            ('2','cliente','1','Juan','500000')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            dni_nif = VALUES(dni_nif) AND iduser= VALUES(iduser)
```

¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Yo quiero que cuando se de el caso de que ya exista a la vez en una misma fila el iduser y el dni_nif, no no la agregue de nuevo y actualice esa misma.

Comment: no termino de entender cual es tu problema

Comment: El AND iduser=VALUES(iduser) creo que me da error, está bien?

Comment: Crees que te da error? que error?

Comment: No es error, es que me inserta una fila nueva donde debería actualizar la existente según esa condición.

Comment: Y la actualice con que valores, si le estas pasando los mismos que estaban?

Comment: Eso es lo de menos, no es lo que pregunto. En ese caso son los mismos pero pueden ser otros.

Comment: Entonces no entiendo nada de tu pregunta. Abajo te contestaron con la sintaxis correcta. Entonces cual es tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos podrias hacer algo asi:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (campo1,campo2)
VALUES (valor1, valor2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   campo1 = valor1, 
   campo2 = valor2,
   ...;
```

ahora aplicado a tu ejemplo podrias intentar algo asi:

```
INSERT INTO contactos
            (iduser, tipo, codigo, nombre, dni_nif )
VALUES
            ('1','cliente','1','Juan','500000'),
            ('1','cliente','2','Maria','500001'),
            ('2','cliente','1','Juan','500000')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            dni_nif = dni_nif,
            iduser = iduser;
```

Para mayor referencia te sugiero revisar esto: 
[Mysql  INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/)

Espero te sirva..suerte..!!

Comment: Pues sigue insertandome las filas y no tiene en cuenta la condición.. Yo quiero que cuando se de el caso de que ya exista en una misma fila el iduser y el dni_nif, no no la agregue de nuevo y actualice esa misma.

Answer (score 0):

Cito completamente la siguiente URL: [Cómo elegir la clave primaria de una tabla](https://inmensia.com/blog/20070223/elegir_clave_primaria_tabla_base_datos_oracle.html)

> A veces tengo la impresión de que elegir las columnas que constituirán
>   la clave primaria de una tabla es una decisión que suele tomarse muy a
>   la ligera, cuando la realidad es que la correcta elección de las
>   claves primarias es un factor decisivo para poder construir un modelo
>   relacional de base de datos bien formado, coherente, mantenible y
>   fácilmente ampliable. Lo más irónico del asunto es que en realidad
>   resulta una tarea muy sencilla si se comprende que ningún valor tomado
>   del dominio que estamos intentando modelar sirve para identificar
>   unívocamente a los registros en base de datos. Dicho de otra forma,
>   **no puede utilizarse como clave primaria una columna que contenga información que tenga significado para los usuarios**; hay que crear
>   una columna expresamente para la clave primaria. O dicho de una
>   tercera forma, si tiene que crear una tabla de personas no utilice DNI
>   como clave primaria.
>
> ¿Pero por qué no es una buena idea elegir DNI como clave primaria?,
>   ¿acaso ese número no nos identifica de forma unívoca?. Pues sí, pero
>   rotundamente NO. Piense por ejemplo que los menores de edad o los
>   ciudadanos de otros paises no tienen normalmente un carnet de
>   identidad, y todo ello sin mencionar además el hecho de que los
>   números del DNI no son únicos, históricamente la misma numeración se
>   ha reutilizado en distintas personas.
>
> Puede que en este momento esté pensando en alternativas muy
>   inteligentes para tratar de resolver los problemas que se plantean en
>   el párrafo anterior, posiblemente mediante la incorporación de nuevas
>   columnas a la clave primaria, pero créame, déjelo, el esfuerzo será
>   inútil, la realidad es que los problemas no desaparecerán, se
>   incrementarán. Por ejemplo, podemos pensar que podremos almacenar
>   menores de edad en nuestra tabla si añadimos una nueva columna a la
>   clave primaria que nos indique si en realidad el DNI es suyo o de su
>   representante legal. Pero ocurre que una persona puede tener varios
>   hijos, con lo cual necesitariamos otra nueva columna para
>   distinguirlos. También podemos pensar que podremos almacenar personas
>   de distintos paises si añadimos una nueva columna que nos indique la
>   nacionalidad de cada persona, permitiendo así además que un mismo
>   número se repita para personas de distintos paises. Pero ocurre que
>   una persona puede tener varias nacionalidades. Y así, vuelta a
>   empezar. Lo normal es que siguiendo esta línea de razonamiento se
>   acabe necesitando facilmente 7 u 8 columnas más. En lineas generales
>   **no se deben utilizar claves primarias compuestas en las tablas maestras**, es decir, claves formadas por varias columnas en las
>   tablas que almacenan las entidades básicas que gestiona un sistema.
>   Complica los modelos haciéndolos difíciles de mantener y ampliar.
>   Piense en el ejemplo anterior, en si persitieramos en nuestra idea
>   original de utilizar DNI como clave primaria, de forma que el día de
>   mañana nos encontráramos un problema de los antes citados, y que
>   además lo solucionáramos añadiendo un nuevo campo a la clave primaria.
>   Pues ocurriría que tendriamos que añadir ese nuevo campo a todas las
>   tablas y procesos que hicieran referencia a la tabla de personas. El
>   cambio no sería único y localizado, si no que se expandería como una
>   enfermedad contagiosa por todas las entidades y procesos del sistema
>   que tuvieran algún tipo de relación con la tabla de personas.
>
> Hay que tener cuidado con las claves compuestas, sobre todo porque a
>   veces se presentan camufladas bajo la apariencia de lo que normalmente
>   se denominan “códigos inteligentes”. Un código inteligente es la unión
>   de varias claves en una sola columna, o sea, una clave primaria
>   compuesta con piel de cordero. Un ejemplo típico de este tipo de
>   código son los localizadores, como el de una entrada de cine en la que
>   figura “S07-F12-B08”, lo que vendría a significar “Sala 7” (S07) “Fila
>   12” (F12) “Butaca 8” (B08). Este tipo de composición se utiliza a
>   veces para identificar las entidades por su ubicación, suponiendo el
>   hecho de que sólo puede haber una entidad en un mismo sitio a un mismo
>   tiempo. El principal problema que plantea este tipo de clave primaria
>   es que a veces, en el mundo real, las entidades se extravían y acaban
>   en localizaciones distintas a las que indican sus códigos, siendo
>   necesario cambiar las claves primarias en la tabla principal y en
>   todas las tablas en las que aparezcan referenciadas, lo que puede ser
>   bastante laborioso, por no decir engorroso y proclive a errores.
>
> El párrafo anterior nos da las dos últimas pistas definitivas para
>   entender el por qué no hay que utilizar DNI como clave primaria de la
>   tabla de personas. La primera pista es que **una clave primaria nunca
>   puede depender de información introducida manualmente**. Si se hace
>   depender el valor de una clave primaria de lo que escriba un usuario
>   se está creando una dependencia brutal de éste con el funcionamiento
>   interno del sistema. El acoplamiento entre capas de una aplicación
>   siempre debe ser débil, de forma que se pueda modificar cada
>   componente de forma individual sin afectar al resto, y en
>   consecuencia, las reglas que rigen el mundo real no tienen porque
>   influir en las que se establecen en el interior de una aplicación. Si
>   la clave primaria de la tabla persona fuera DNI, y el día de mañana se
>   decidiera utilizar el NIF, entonces se tendría que cambiar todo el
>   modelo y los procesos para gestionar la clave como un campo
>   alfanumérico en vez de como sólo nunérico. Si DNI no fuera clave
>   entonces bastaría con cambiar ese campo concreto de forma aislada.
>
> La segunda pista es que **una clave primaria nunca ha de poder
>   modificarse**. La clave primaria de un registro identifica de forma
>   unívoca a un objeto dentro del dominio que se está modelando. Si se
>   cambia la clave primaria de un registro se produce una “mutación” por
>   la cual el registro pasa a representar a otro objeto. Este aspecto
>   quizás sea un poco sutil de entender, sobre todo por que conlleva
>   cierto nivel de abstracción. Una persona se podría decir que es la
>   suma de sus características individuales, así como del lugar que ocupa
>   en cualquiera de las dimensiones en las que se proyecta (y
>   posiblemente de su ausencia en las dimensiones en las que no se
>   proyecta). Es una entidad, un ser único y distinguible. Su clave
>   primaria ha de identificarlo de forma unívoca, si se cambia
>   representaría otra entidad, no al individuo original. Piense en
>   términos de variables, como las que se utilizan normalmente en
>   cualquier lenguaje de programación. Primero se definen, y luego se les
>   puede cambiar su contenido, de igual forma que una persona puede
>   cambiarse de ropa o de peinado. Las variables siempren hacen
>   referencia a una misma información concreta, independientemente del
>   valor que contengan en un momento dado. Con las personas ocurre lo
>   mismo, da igual el peinado o la ropa que llevemos, e incluso donde nos
>   encontremos, por encima de todo seguimos siendo nosotros mismos, no
>   otros. Si a una persona se le cambia su DNI porque se introdujo un
>   número equivocado en el alta, debe seguir siendo la misma entidad que
>   se insertó originalmente en el sistema, no otra distinta que implique
>   una actualización masiva de las relaciones.
>
> En definitiva, la forma correcta de identificar las entidades en una
>   tabla es utilizar un código o identificador único que carezca de
>   significado en el mundo real. Un simple valor numérico generado de
>   forma secuencial es suficiente. La idea es crear una tabla con una
>   primera columna de tipo numérico que sirva como clave primaria. En el
>   ejemplo inicial, la tabla de personas, podría ser algo como: ID_PERSON
>   NUMBER(10) NOT NULL. De forma que cuando se inserte una primera
>   persona en la tabla se le asigne el valor 1 como clave primaria (ó
>   1527, es indistinto). Cuando se inserte una nueva persona se le asigne
>   el 2 (ó 1528). Y así sucesivamente. De esta forma no hay posibilidad
>   de conflictos, o lo que es lo mismo, de encontrarse con errores por
>   claves primarias duplicadas. Cada persona queda emparejada con un
>   identificador que le distingue unívocamente del resto. Y lo dicho para
>   persona sirve para cualquier tipo de entidad. Un motor no se
>   identifica por su número de bastidor, sino por su clave primaria. Un
>   televisor no se identifica por su número de serie, sino por su clave
>   primaria. Una factura no se identifica por su número, sino por su
>   clave primaria. Un usuario no indentifica por su nombre, sino por
>   clave primaria. ¿Captan la idea?
>
> Esta forma de definir las claves suele crear bastante confusión en los
>   desarrolladores no acostumbrados a esta forma de modelar. Las primeras
>   cuestiones que se suelen plantear son la tocantes al rendimiento,
>   sobre todo porque las búsquedas por columnas como DNI son bastantes
>   habituales. Al dejar de ser parte de la clave primaria hay que definir
>   índices adicionales sobre las tablas para estas columnas. Algunos
>   diseñadores reniegan espontáneamente cuando se sugiere añadir varios
>   índices sobre una misma tabla alegando que corresponde a un mal
>   diseño. Pero entonces, ¿para qué diablos queremos los índices?. Otra
>   cuestión habitual que se suele plantear es cómo generar las claves
>   primarias. La respuesta creo que depende en gran medida de las
>   herramientas que se utilicen para desarrollar. Oracle por ejemplo
>   proporciona los objetos de tipo SEQUENCE, que generan valores
>   secuenciales de forma atómica. Algunos gestores permiten indicar que
>   las columnas sean autoincrementales, de forma que cada vez que se
>   inserta un registro se genera automáticamente un nuevo valor. Los
>   “gurús” suelen divagar acerca de aspectos tales como si es necesario
>   utilizar una única secuencia para todas las entidades del sistema o
>   una secuencia distinta para cada tabla. Lo que está claro es que nunca
>   se debe ejecutar COUNT o MAX sobre las tablas para obtener el
>   siguiente secuencial, son atentados directos contra la integridad y el
>   rendimiento de la aplicación. Otra cuestión que se suele plantear es
>   el tema del tamaño requerido por la columna de la clave primaria. Un
>   tamaño de 10 representa una cantidad de diez billones de valores
>   posibles, suficiente para la mayoría de aplicaciones de propósito
>   general. Lo que hay que hacer sobre todo es que todas las tablas
>   tengan una columna de clave primaria con el mismo tamaño, no cada una
>   con un tamaño distinto ajustado en función de su ocupación estimada.
>   Referente a esta última cuestión, hay que matizar que añadir una
>   columna de tamaño diez no implica añadir automáticamente 10 bytes por
>   registro, el espacio adicional requerido dependerá enteramente del
>   gestor de base de datos que se esté utilizando.
>
> Trabajar con tablas definidas de esta forma por primera vez puede
>   resultar un tanto inquietante al principio. Puede parecer que mantener
>   la coherencia de tantos identificadores es algo complicado, pero no lo
>   es, de hecho, hoy en día es la forma más natural de diseñar y
>   trabajar. Simplifica el diseño de las capas de persistencia con las
>   que se consiguen mapear los objetos en memoria, al tiempo que ayuda a
>   separar la información que resulta significativa para los usuarios de
>   la forma en que se gestiona internamente. Si sus herramientas no
>   soportan esta forma de trabajar vaya pensando seriamente en
>   sustituirlas por otras nuevas.
>
> Y por último, no quería dejar de comentar el hecho de que seguramente
>   todos estos razonamientos parezcan complicaciones innecesarias para
>   sistemas pequeños en ambientes muy controlados. Sin embargo, pensar
>   así es olvidar una máxima informática que hay que tener siempre muy
>   presente: ¡los requerimientos siempren cambian!

Comment: Le daria un +1000000.. si no fuera porque por mas extenso que sea, es mas un comentario que una respuesta...